# Changing user nickname on join (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I was advised to try with `discord.js` and it still doesn't work.

My code is:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
   guild.members.forEach(r => r.setNickname(nick + r.name));
});
```

If anyone would help me figure out why this doesn't work, I will appreciate it.

Comment: You appear to be trying to set *every* member's nickname. Surely you just want to set that one member's nick?

Comment: The question is not clear. Please update your question.

Comment: Can include what `r` is?

Answer (score 1):

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  m.setNickname(r => r.username);
});
```

This Code sets the Nickname of a joined User to his Username.
As much as i could understand this is what you want to Achive, right?

Comment: I have tried this, but it gave me an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setNickname' of undefined

Comment: Internal accidentally switched variables, try member.setNickname instead

Comment: Ah yes, my fault sorry

Comment: i have tried the changed, no errors now but it doesnt change the nickname though i did write member.setNickname(r => r.username("︻デ═一" + r.username)); . maybe something is wrong here?